# Is it possible to track how people use Microsoft Office Products?

Tags: microsoft-office-2007

My company is considering a move to Google Apps. Our first step is to find out how everyone in our company is using MS Office.

We could ask them directly but we believe we'll get a much less bias answer by tracking usage.  We're not looking to watch what people do, we don't care what they're emailing.  We just want to track what features they're using.  For instance, we want to know

1. When they `Orb->Open`, use a macro, `Review->Track Changes` in Word?
2. how they're using Outlook.  Do they have a signature?  Are they inserting attachments?  If so, how big?

and others...

Is this possible?

Comment: good question I know that you can opt in for sending this info to MS but I don't know if the info can be collected easily internally,.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, it isn't possible.

I do agree that if you asked people this question they wouldn't really be able to answer it without bias. The problem I found after people move from one software package to another is that they start to miss these little features that are hardly worth mentioning but are only important when its removed. I would still try asking people what features they use and why.

If many people do a similar job ask one of them if they would be ok going onto google apps for a week, this will give you a pretty good idea of any missing features and training that would be required for that department/group.

Comment: Starting out with a small test group is a great idea

Comment: Ok, I like the test group idea.  But, how can I go about splitting my domain (company.com) so that user1@company.com goes into my Exchange server and user2@company.com goes to Google Apps?  How do I setup the MX records on my DNS entry?